# Add invisible element in react

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have something that looks like the following

```
<Container>
<LeftBlock />
<RightBlock/>
<Container>

#container{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

#rightBlock{
display: flex;
    float: right;
}
```

this works as expected. Left block is on the left and the right is on the right. Sometimes I want to hide the left block

```
<Container>
{(shouldShow) ? (
<LeftBlock />
) : null }
<RightBlock/>
<Container>
```

The right block is now on the left. I also tried this but it didn't work

```
<Container>
{(shouldShow) ? (
<LeftBlock />
) : (<div></div>) }
<RightBlock/>
<Container>
```

adding one Char inside the div `<div>.</div>` works and the right block appear on the right of the screen. How could I solve this? Shall I ann an "invisible" element instead of the left block?

Comment: `float: right` didn't work? Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on https://codesandbox.io/s/new?

Comment: if  any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the left part is has `display:none`
use `justify-content:flex-end;` on parent to keep the block on right, and remove the float on left block

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}


.left {
  width:50%;
  background-color: teal;
  display:none;
}


.right {
   width:50%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean it?

you just need to predefine className 
depending on the shouldShow
eg: `className={container ${shouldShow && 'disabled-left-component'}}`

`<Container>
{shouldShow && <LeftBlock />}
<RightBlock/>
<Container>`

Comment: This also dose not work, the RightBlock will be on the left

Comment: and `.disabled-left-component {justify-content: flex-end}` or  align-items

Answer (score 0):

try using css grid.I feel its more cleaner way-

```
.left{
   grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
.right {
 grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way you can solve this problem.

**Here is working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4ypv31k3v) in react**

> **Note:** here I am using jquery for the only demonstration purpose.

1. add `justify-content: flex-end;`

```js
$("#toggle-left").on('click', function(){
    $('.left').toggle();
});
```

```css
#container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.left {
 padding: 50px 0;
 background-color: black;
 flex: 1 1 50%;
 max-width: 50%;
}
.right {
padding: 50px 0;
background-color: red;
flex: 1 1 50%;
max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>

<button id="toggle-left">Toggle Left</button>
```